# Copy FormatCondition Object From Custom Collection

Tags: ms-access, vba

I know I'm probably trying to do something sort of abnormal. I need to save (and delete) all FormatCondition objects from a Controls FormatConditions collection. And then later I need to recreate/reapply those same FormatCondition objects back to the same control again.

It seems I can copy them successfully but I get errors when I try to reapply those same FormatCondition objects from my own Collection object. I suspect that what's happening here is that I'm not actually copying the objects in my SaveAndDelete routine as I think I am. And if that's the case, how can I go about actually cloning these objects so they persist after I run f.Delete?

```
Private SavedFC As New Collection

Private Sub SaveAndDeleteFormatConditions(c as Control)
    Dim f As FormatCondition
    For Each f In c.FormatConditions
        SavedFC.Add f
        f.Delete
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub RecreateFormatConditions(c as control)
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 1
    If SavedFC.Count > 0 Then
        Dim f1 As FormatCondition, f2 As FormatCondition
        For Each f1 In SavedFC

            'Error 2467 occurs here: The expression you entered refers to an object that is closed or doesn't exist
            Set f2 = c.FormatConditions.Add(f1.Type, f1.Operator, f1.Expression1, f1.Expression2)
            With f2
                .BackColor = f1.BackColor
                .FontBold = f1.FontBold
                .FontItalic = f1.FontItalic
                .FontUnderline = f1.FontUnderline
                .ForeColor = f1.ForeColor
            End With
            SavedFC(i).Delete
            i = i + 1
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you choose to do deletions within your `For` loops for the object you're iterating through? I've done the same, but I get paranoid about potential anomalies and prefer to delete or set to `Nothing` after the loop. It's too bad Access doesn't seem to have an equivalent to `.ClearFormats`, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

This line causes the problem:

```
f.Delete
```

What happens here is you add an item to the collection (it is an object, so you operate with the reference). Then, you delete the object itself. Now, you have a collection of pointers that point to the deleted/non-existent objects. That's why you get 2467 error later.

Comment: You just confirmed my suspicions. Can you answer the main part of my question though: **And if that's the case, how can I go about actually cloning these objects so they persist after I run f.Delete?**

Comment: one of the possible ways would be defining a separate object(class module) to hold the formattings and populate the collection of those. you can get some ideas from here: http://www.di-mgt.com.au/cl_Simple.html